# Trying to config Serilog with .net core 2 console app using generic HostBuilder

Tags: .net-core, serilog

Trying to follow the docs here
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting

Have these packages referenced in my project

> ```
> <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.8.0" />
> <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />
> ```

When I try to add the line UseSeriLog, it cant be recognized

> Error CS1061  'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'UseSeriLog' and no accessible extension method 'UseSeriLog' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'IHostBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My main method:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                      .WriteTo.File(@"d:\temp\consoleapp.log")
                      .CreateLogger();

        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
         .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => { configHost.AddCommandLine(args); })
         .UseContentRoot(@"D:\Services\BldgRunner\")
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
         {

             var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
             config.AddCommandLine(args);
             config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
             config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
         })
         .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
         {
             //Inject additional services as needed
             services.AddHostedService<JobRunner>();
         })
         **.UseSeriLog()**
         .Build();


        if (isService)
        {
            await hostBuilder.RunAsServiceAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await hostBuilder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` for use with a generic host.

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.0" />
```